# Read multiple excel files

Tags: c#, excel

I am new to CSharp programming. I have a requirement to read multiple excel files from a folder. I don't know the number of excel files in that folder. I want to read all the files one by one. To read one single file, I have written some piece of code. I want to apply this code to read all files in a folder one by one. Please let me know the way. Here is my code.

```
class RatWalk
{
    public List<RatStep> steps = new List<RatStep>();
    string[] Individal_Runs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\AG_Winter\Desktop\Individual_Runs");
    public void LoadFromFile(String fileName) // reads data from excel file
    {
        steps.Clear();
        XlsFile file = new XlsFile(fileName);
        try
        {
           // Everything I wanna do
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("No run");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thank you all. I dont know how to reply for the posts because the comments should be in limited number of characters. So I am typing it here.

In my program, I want to read xlsx files one by one from a folder. I am using a button to browse a single file as of now. But then I wanna use this button to browse the folder in which I have the files. So that when I select this folder, the program should automatically run all the files in the folder, one by one. here is what I did before this.

[\code = c#]
 class RatWalk
    {
        public List steps = new List();

```
    public void LoadFromFile(String fileName)                       // reads data from excel file
    {

            steps.Clear();

            XlsFile file = new XlsFile(fileName);
try{
//everything I wanna do
```

}catch{}
}

```
 private void InitializeComponent()                             
        {
            EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(OnClick);
            button.Text = "Browse for the XLS file";                    
            // button properties                                       
            this.Controls.Add(button);
}
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)            // Browses for the file and loads the selected Excel file
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                return;
            ratWalk.LoadFromFile(fileDialog.FileName);

           // Whatever I wanna do   
        }
```

Here, I want to change it in such a way that when i click the button and select the folder, it should run all the files in the folder one by one.

Please let me know how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: May you please provide what `XlsFile` stands for? :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY: XlsFile is a class in FelxCel library to read or write xlsx files...

Answer (score 4):

I'll point you to an example, and leave up to you to do the rest.

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
   // do something with fileName
   Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

BTW, this doesn't iterate trough subfolders.

Comment: I have tried the above in the following way..

public void LoadFromFile(String fileName)                       
        {
            string[] Individual_Runs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Individual_Runs");
            foreach (string IR in Individual_Runs) {
                  
             XlsFile file = new XlsFile(IR);

Everything I wanna do
}

And then I wanna use a button and onclick method to browse the directory and run through each file one by one

my code is :

Comment: Are you asking how to open folder or?

Comment: there is openFileDialog control. Check google, and work it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string[] Individal_Runs = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\testfiles");
        foreach (string s in Individal_Runs)
        {
            try
            {
String theConnString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + s + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(theConnString);
    objConn.Open();

    OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", objConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
    DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();
    objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");

     //Your code here

    objConn.Close();


            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("No run");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a path to target folder.
2. Once you get the folder, programatically get all the excel files under it and put them in a list.
3. Your code to read one excel file, iterate over the list of excel files and use the same function in loop.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileOperationsSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Change this path to the directory you want to read
            string path = "C:\\Junk";             
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            Console.WriteLine("File Name                       Size        Creation Date and Time");
            Console.WriteLine("=================================================================");
            foreach (FileInfo flInfo in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                String name = flInfo.Name;
                long size = flInfo.Length;
                DateTime creationTime = flInfo.CreationTime;
                Console.WriteLine("{0, -30:g} {1,-12:N0} {2} ", name, size, creationTime);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```